# C# How Do I Locate A Form On A Web Page In C#?

Tags: c#

I am writing an application that needs to be able to locate to a specified URL and then automatically enter a username and password for the form that pops up when the website is loaded.

How can I programmatically achieve this in C#?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should be able to do this using [System.Net.WebRequest](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.webrequest.aspx) and doing an HTTP POST.  [Here](http://www.artoftest.com/home.aspx) is an example of this being done.

If for some reason this is some strange web page and the POST won't work the other alternative is to use a browser automation framework like http://watin.sourceforge.net/ or [WebAii](http://www.artoftest.com/home.aspx) to automate a browser to do this but I don't recommend this unless you really can't so it any other way because it will be slower, likely less robust and is more of a pain in general.